# Why isn't this print method working?

Tags: objective-c, printf, nslog

It works when I use `NSLog`, but not `printf`. I want to use `printf` because then all the elements in `setA` will be displayed in one line.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define INTOBJ(v) [NSNumber numberWithInteger: v]

@interface NSSet (Printing) 
-(void) print;
@end

@implementation NSSet (Printing)
-(void) print {
    for (NSNumber *element in self) 
        printf("%li", (long) [element integerValue]);
}

@end

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableSet *setA = [NSMutableSet setWithObjects:INTOBJ(3), INTOBJ(10), INTOBJ(1), INTOBJ(5), nil];

        [setA print];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you're trying to run this on a device in iOS, right? If you run in the simulator, `printf` should work as well.

Comment: The question was ansered here as well:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924831/iphone-debugging-real-device][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924831/iphone-debugging-real-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSLog is essentially a different version of printf that allows for Objective C stuff, while printf can't handle Objective C material.

If your printf method isn't working, this is probably the problem.

Comment: No. He's properly getting the value - just not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

try `-longValue` instead of `-integerValue` it should cast them implicitly, but you never know...

Answer (score -1):

Convert from the NSNumber which is an object into an NSInteger first, then you can output to the console with your printf statement, and all of the integers should appear on one line.

> ```
> for(NSNumber *element in setA)
> {
>     NSInteger num = [element intValue];
>     printf("%li", (long)num);
>
> }
> ```

Comment: OP is already doing this, and is even using the correct method to get an `NSInteger`: `integerValue`. `intValue` returns an `int`.