# How to direct printf output to the same target as NSLog?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, printf, nslog

How can i make the output of printf appear in the Xcode Organizer console view? While debugging on a connected device i can see printf output right among NSLog output in th debug console in Xcode, but i can see only NSLog output on the Organizer console.

I'm developing in Objective-C++ and use printf for logging pure c++ code. Ultimately i wish to have this output from the app available from the time the device has been disconnected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924831/iphone-debugging-real-device) description how to achieve it. It looks like there is no another ability to direct `printf` to Organizer.